# Non-Flash Flip Book [Cross-Browser]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, cross-browser

I am starting a new project and my main home page element will be a Flip Book.

**I prefer staying away from Flash and HTML5.**

The problem is that I am having a hard time finding a Full Cross Browser Jquery/Javascript Flip Book that has the capability of the CLICK AND DRAG event. (I don't want a normal click and flip.)

**Does anyone have or know of a full cross browser Click and Drag Flip Book?**

OR if you have an example, not cross browser, what alternative cross browser overrides would be best to use?

Comment: Why do you reject out "HTML5" right away? When one proves that it's cross-browser compatible, then there's no harm in using it.

Comment: I am not rejecting it, I don't prefer it. If I can't get a full crossbrowser html5 example that works in ie7/8 that would be perfect... thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link with a few choices :

http://cssnerd.com/2011/12/08/animated-css3-pageflip-flipbook-with-a-little-jquery/

On the page you will see :

**jQuery version** (that @Arno posted)

- They updated it on August 8, 2012 and is looking much better
- Works on iPad
- IE7 & IE8 some shading issues when paging (im not even gonna test IE6)
- http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/

**Pure CSS3 version**

- Only works on Chrome (and buggy on Safari)
- Smooth page flip, but too limited
- http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/page-flip.html

**HTML5 version** (coz we can't ignore the non-crossbrowser html5 anymore)

- It only gives the example : http://www.20thingsilearned.com
- Here is the proper tutorial : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/

**3d flipbook without a HTML5 canvas version**

- Major performance issues
- http://webkit-os.pixelass.com/flipbooktest/

Comment: heh.. that is my blog LOL. I was just looking for a free pageflip and landed here. I never finished mine and turn.js is just too expensive. Seems like I really gotta write a new one myself.

Comment: haha! :) That is awesome! Let me know when you have updated your version so I can update links..or even if you find a new free html Flip Book. cheers

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps missed out as it was not available at the time, I've had great success (due to it's simplicity) with [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/)

It's also got a HTML4 version, so it's not only HTML5.

Comment: Is it free? Ain't nobody got time for that :P

Comment: yes, the 3rd release is under a non-commercial BSD license and you need to pay for commercial licenses.

Comment: Not sure if I must mark this as the correct answer? Can I add this to the list of options on the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/. It uses jQuery and jQuery UI, and supports click and drag.

Comment: Doesn't have a nice feel to it, and bugs out sometimes with a nasty flicker. But thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PDF-to-HTML flip generator](http://codecanyon.net/item/pdf-to-html-flipbook-generator/3791124?sso?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=cphelefu).